# Updating Excel sheets when a shape changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a cell to show the height of a shape after the shape height changes when dragging the shape handle. I can successfully do this with an event handler but that requires deselecting the shape. Is it possible to show the new height of the shape in a cell without deselecting the shape? Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim heightVar As Integer

heightVar = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("boxbox1")).Height

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = heightVar 

End Sub
```

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I place a TextBox on my sheet. I make sure cells **A1** and **A2** are empty. I run the following macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1")
    While Range("A1") = ""
        Range("A2") = s.Height
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

If you select the Shape and change its height, cell **A2** will respond.

To stop the macro from looping, just put something in cell **A1**.

Comment: Yes, I was able to use this to do what I need. Thank you so much!